# Data Cleaning of CSV using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file as shown below:

```
                   100%Q,mean(ms),P50(ms),P99(ms),p99.9(ms),#Samples
QCT1,0.0376542  0.044935    0.090388    0.091279    1760105,,,,
QCT2,0.0489372  0.044953    0.090606    0.091422    1354230,,,,
QCT3,0.0447087  0.045008    0.046186    0.063825    123448,,,,
RCT,0.38646 0.38588 0.844293    1.01548 7295875,,,,
WCT,NA  NA  NA  NA  NA,,,,
```

I want to clean all this messy spaces on the header as well as all the unnecessary commas and turn it into another data frame whether it is comma/space separated so that I can work forward with some comparison with another data frame.

I have already tried few things like grepping few columns and cleaning the header and everything but here is my result at the moment with pandas :
Data-frame looks like below when it tab separated:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("results/actual.csv",sep='\t')
df1


                         100%Q,mean(ms),P50(ms),P99(ms),p99.9(ms),#Samples
QCT1,0.03 0.05 0.09 0.09                                          5,,,,
QCT2,0.04 0.04 0.09 0.09                                          0,,,,
QCT3,0.04 0.08 0.04 0.06                                          8,,,,
RCT,0.3  0.3 0.8 1.01                                             5,,,,
WCT,NA NaN NaN NaN                                                NA,,,,
```

Further output of the data-frame looks like below as default:

```
df2=pd.read_csv("results/actual.csv",usecols=range(0,6))
df2

100%Q mean(ms)                    P50(ms)   P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)  #Samples
QCT1  0.03\t0.05\t0.09\t0.09\t5    NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN
QCT2  0.04\t0.04\t0.09\t0.09\t0    NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN
QCT3  0.04\t0.08\t0.04\t0.06\t8    NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN
RCT   0.3\t0.3\t0.8\t0.01\t5       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN
WCT   NA\tNA\tNA\tNA\tNA           NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN
```

I am expecting it to look like this:

```
100%Q    mean(ms)  P50(ms)   P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)  #Samples
QCT1     0.03      0.05      0.09     0.09       5
QCT2     0.04      0.04      0.09     0.09       0
QCT3     0.04      0.08      0.04     0.06       8
RCT      0.3       0.3       0.8      1.01       5
WCT      NA        NaN       NaN      NaN        NA
```

Problem is with extra white-spaces as well as white-spaces in headers. Is there a way I can turn this into a data-frame with a common delimiter. 
.It would be great if someone could help me with this who has faced this and solved it with Pandas.

Note: Please ignore the values from the actual table as I had manipulated it to fit it into a frame so that it looks good and make sense to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file with the `,` seperator, so that only the `means(ms)` column has to be processed. Next you can combine multiple whitespaces to one with `' '.join(x.split())` and split all the values inside `means(ms)` by whitespace with `split(' ')`. Use list comprehension to combine all results into a list of lists and insert into the columns `1:` of the dataframe.

```
df=pd.read_csv("results/actual.csv",sep=',')
df[df.columns[1:]] = [' '.join(x.split()).split(' ') for x in df['mean(ms)']]
```

If your values inside `means(ms)` are seprarated by tabulator, use:

```
df[df.columns[1:]] = [x.split('\t') for x in df['mean(ms)']]
```

[image]

Comment: @Hemant Kumar, why do you revoked my answer, could you please tell me, what was wrong? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your column headers are separated by commas and your index column is separated by a comma from the rest of the values. The values are tab-separated. You can read with the "\t|," separator, rename the columns and then index by your first column. Does this do what you want? I am assuming your file doesn't contain commas or tabs not meant to separate anything.

```
df = pd.read_csv('results/actual.csv', sep='\t|,', index_col='100%Q')
```